# Compare a data type using a string or other format

Tags: c#, types

I'd like to set a data type without having to create an extra variable in C#. Rather than creating an empty variable and then comparing a type.

```
CustomType empty; //empty variable
CustomType RealFooBar = new CustomType("extremeFoobar", false) //custom datatype with data in it

if(RealFooBar.GetType() == empty.GetType())
     //operation
```

I would rather do it like this:

```
CustomType RealFooBar // already has data

if(RealFooBar.GetType() == {CustomType})
     //operation
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried `typeof(CustomType)` one time but it didn't seem to work that way. Or I didn't do it right.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't seem to work"? Assuming you don't have errors in your code, something like this `o.GetType() == typeof(Foo)` should give you the correct result.

Comment: Now I feel stupid. For whatever reason, it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `typeof` if you know the type beforehand (at compile time) and use `GetType` only when you don't and it changes during runtime.

Another thing, if you only need to compare you can use `is` keyword, ref:
[IS keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

So any of these should work:

```cs
if(RealFooBar is string)
if(RealFooBar.GetType() == typeof(string))
```

Edit: Adding clarification of solution. Even though 2nd example works in this specific case it is recommended to use `is` in almost all cases. Reason being is that 2nd example is "exact type comparison" and will make it much harder to use inheritance. Given example below you can see how it will behave when used for classes.

```cs
class Foo {}
class Bar : Foo {}
```

```cs
var instanceOfBar = new Bar();
var instanceOfFoo = new Foo();

//works for base class as expected
if(instanceOfFoo is Foo) //true
if(instanceOfFoo is Bar) //false
if(instanceOfFoo.GetType() == typeof(Foo)) //true
if(instanceOfFoo.GetType() == typeof(Bar)) //false

//exact type checks could behave "unexpectedly" for classes that inherit
if(instanceOfBar is Foo) //true
if(instanceOfBar is Bar) //true
if(instanceOfBar.GetType() == typeof(Foo)) //false ???
if(instanceOfBar.GetType() == typeof(Bar)) //true
```

I'am using the word unexpectedly in a sense, that we cannot know whenever there will be new classes in the future that inherit from `Foo` and code that was already written could stop working or behave unexpectedly.